# Non-continuous span

Tags: html

Is there any way to get a `<span>` element that contains some text, but not other text, which is in the middle? I tried using two `<span>` elements with the same ID but it doesn't appear to have the desired effects.

Edit: A little more background, although I don't think this is an exact XY problem.

I've got a system right now where I highlight text that has been linked to specifically by using `span:target`. The problem is that this can only do one span at a time and I wish to link specifically to multiple segments of text on the same page. In addition, these segments are non-continuous with each other *as well as* with text I don't want to be highlighted. That is, given the sequence of XYZXYZ, then I wish to highlight the X text, *if* it was linked to, and the Z text if it was linked to, but never the Y text.

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what's the real issue? (The answer is either "no" or "more elements and absolute positioning" depending on what you mean by "contains").

Comment: An ID must be document-wide unique!

Comment: @Quentin: The issue is that I have two disjoint sequences of text which I wish to be styled differently if they have been targetted *by the same target ID*.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bCHye/1/

Comment: @JohnH: That is styled statically. I need to style it dynamically depending on which element was targetted. Also, I'm not entirely sure how that's going to work with multiple disjoint overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. HTML is hierarchical, so you cannot split up an element into disjoint pieces.

Furthermore, a span is, by its very nature, continuous content.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to wanting different formatting in the middle of your text?

If you're HTML looks like this:

```
<span id="mySpan">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
```

And you want `Ispum` styled differently, you can do:

```
<span id="mySpan">Lorem <span>Ipsum</span> Dolor</span>
```

And then have overriding styles for this "inner span":

```
span#mySpan span
{
   //styles for inner span text here
}
```

Comment: I'm using a `span:target`, and I tried doing something similar, so `span:target span { // styles }`, but it didn't seem to have any effect on the Ipsum text. Furthermore, I'm not sure how this technique would cope if I needed to *nest* the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Link to a containing element and use a descendent selector.

```
span:target span.highlightMe {}
```

Comment: This works in the simple Lorem Ispum Dolor case, but not if I have something like Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor and wish to apply to all the Lorems or all the Dolors or all the Ipsums, for example.

Comment: You appear to have deviated a *long* way from the intended purpose of `:target`. It is there to style what has been linked to, not allow you to highlight arbitrary bits of content. You should look at dynamically generating the span elements with some program logic, either server side or with JS.

Comment: I am styling what has been linked to. It's just that in this case, what has been linked to is rather disjoint.